# Get new access_code without user interaction?

Tags: php, sql, facebook

I do have access to the access keys for my users via offline access but is their a way to refresh those codes automatically without having the user re-accessing my app?

Comment: yes. basically im trying to make it that if a user changes their password, i can get the new access code without them having to access the application to refresh it. My server would check 1 time a week to see if the app has a invalid code due to password change and if it sees it update it on the fly. Right now my server is doing something similar that if a app has been reauthorized to remove data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user changes password, offline_access expires. This is the main purpose. You can't do anything but the ask the app user to grant offline_access again.

For these you have:

> https://developers.facebook.com/apps > Advanced > Deauthorize Callback

to be notified when the issue happend.

However, probably you have user's mail adres, you can send mail asking visit app and grant the permission.